# Stop Duplicating Terms in a Foreach Loop

Tags: php

I have a foreach loop that prints out custom posts which uses a custom taxonomy. The user can then add whatever term/s they like to each post. 
This then prints out a list of terms on the custom template page; and links them all to a filter.

My issue is that when two posts contain the same term; it outputs/prints the term out twice. How can I solve this?

Here is a temporary example: http://website-test-lab.com/sites/zuludawn/video-archive/

Here is my full page template code:

```
<?php
// WP_Query arguments
$args = array (
    'post_type'          => 'cpt-video-arc',
    'posts_per_page' => '-1'
);

// The Query
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
?>

<div class="entry-content units-row group">

    <div class="category-list category-list-video-archive">
                Filter by tags:
                <button class="filter" data-filter="all">Show All</button>

                <?php $terms = array(); ?>

                <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>

                    <?php $terms_tags = wp_get_post_terms( $query->post->ID, array( 'video-arc-tags-taxonomy' ) ); ?>

                    <?php foreach ( $terms_tags as $term_tag ) { ?>
                        <?php $terms[$term_tag->slug] = '<button class="filter" data-filter=".'.$term_tag->slug.'">'.$term_tag->name.'</button>'; ?>
                        <?php echo implode($terms,' '); ?>
                    <?php } ?>

                <?php endwhile; ?>

    </div><!-- .category-list -->

</div><!-- .entry-content -->

<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Comment: I think you are talking about terms, not taxonomies. `video-arc-tags-taxonomy` is the taxonomy, everyrhing below it is called terms :-)

Comment: Yes, apologies. Updated the question.

Comment: You should escape your output, if your terms name was `</button><script>alert('hello');</script><button>`... the `esc_attr` should fix that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would tend to do this:

```
$terms = array();
$terms_tags = wp_get_post_terms( $query->post->ID, array( 'post_tag' ) ); 
foreach ( $terms_tags as $term_tag ) {
  $terms[$term_tag->slug] = '<button class="filter" data-filter=".'.$term_tag->slug.',">'.$term_tag->name.'</button>';
}
echo implode($terms,', ');
```

It leverages the fact that PHP does not allow duplicate array keys, and thus avoids the overhead of function calls.

In your case, it should look like this (without all of that PHP tag spam):

```
$query = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>
<div class="entry-content units-row group">
  <div class="category-list category-list-video-archive">
    Filter by tags:
    <button class="filter" data-filter="all">Show All</button><?php 
    $terms = array(); 
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) : 
      $query->the_post();
      $terms_tags = wp_get_post_terms( $query->post->ID, array( 'video-arc-tags-taxonomy' ) );
      foreach ( $terms_tags as $term_tag ) { 
        $terms[$term_tag->slug] = '<button class="filter" data-filter=".'.$term_tag->slug.'">'.$term_tag->name.'</button>';  
      }
    endwhile; 
    echo implode($terms,' '); // this goes outside the while loop ?>
  </div><!-- .category-list -->
</div><!-- .entry-content -->
```

Comment: I got distracted :) See the edit @ialocin

Comment: Thank you for the help but it has given me the same output I'm afraid. Duplicate terms. Note: I've added a temporary URL to the original question.

Comment: There is something about the application that is unclear. This should work. Please add some detail to the question. Where and how is the code used? What is the context?

Comment: I've updated my original code above. It seems to only get the terms for the first post and not all of the others.

Comment: As websupporter said, the `$variable = array();` declaration has to be outside the `while`. @HuwRowlands

Comment: The implementation is wrong, you are resetting the the array at every iteration.

Comment: @s_ha_dum: If I remove the while loop then only the terms from the first post appears. If I add the while loop, the terms get duplicated. Sorry; I am confused as to which area of my code is incorrect causing this issue. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @HuwRowlands : see if that is more what you are looking for.

Answer (score 6):

What about this:

```
<?php 
$already_used = array();
foreach ( $terms_tags as $term_tag ) : 
    if( ! in_array( $term_tag, $already_used ): ?>
        <button class="filter" data-filter=".<?php echo $term_tag->slug; ?>"><?php echo $term_tag->name; ?></button>
        <?php 
        $already_used[] = $term_tag; 
    endif;
 endforeach; 
?>
```

Explanation: You create an array, where you save which terms you've already used. If the current term is in this array, it will not be printed. Otherwise it will be printed and put into the array.

EDIT: You have to put the `$already_used = array();` before the while `( $query->have_posts() )` of course.

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what i was looking for